# Can someone identify this crash?

Tags: accident-investigation

I watched an episode of Air Crash Investigation or something else a while ago,  I want to know which one this was:

What I know is that during takeoff, the aircraft received a warning saying some part of the autopilot wasn't functional however they continued the takeoff as it wasn’t a big deal. They reset the flight computer, but since the aircraft was old and the flap settings and everything was set to normal, the aircraft began banking to the right and it crashed.

Answer (score 5):

You might be referring to [LAPA Flight 3142](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPA_Flight_3142) (Episode 9 of Season 17). An alarm sounded during takeoff because the flaps were not set, but the pilots ignored the warnings. The aircraft failed to lift off the ground and crashed at the end of the runway.

If that's not the one, [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mayday_episodes) on Wikipedia should help you locate the episode.